# meteor js galaxy routing sub directory to an external wordpress

Tags: wordpress, meteor, galaxy-apps

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

I have my domain from GoDaddy and app is built on meteor js and its hosted on Galaxy hosting. I want to redirect all of my requests to "/blog/" to an external WordPress site hosted on a different server.

For example, if someone visits

http://example.com/blog/some-article -> this req should open some-article article hosted on a different server.

Can you please suggest on how to achieve this?

galaxy hosting is very easy, cost-effective and is giving my app very quick response times, <50ms. I am looking to stick with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with just taking the user to the right place without a 301 redirect then you can set `document.location` in your `/blog/:slug` route.

For example using [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router):

```
FlowRouter.route('/blog/:slug', {
  action(params) {
    document.location = 'https://otherserver/'+params.slug;
  }
});
```

Using react-router would be similar.

If you want to issue a 301 redirect that would need to come from the server and I'm not sure you can do that in Galaxy without having control of the nginx config file which they don't give you.